# How to filter the update not to include a parent field when using change stream in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, changestream

My document example:

```js
{
id: 139234234,
count: 12,
type: apple,
buyer: [
    {name: "peter", price: 1.23, max: 129}, 
    {name: "alex", price: 1.4, "max": 12146}
    ]
}
```

My update:

```js
db.updateMany({ id: 139234234 }, [
    {
      $set: {
        buyer: {
          $concatArrays: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: "$buyer",
                cond: {
                    { $ne: ["$$this.name", "john"] },
                },
              },
            },
            [
              {
                name: "john",
                price: 12,
                max: 234,
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

I frequently do this kind of update in `buyer` field, what should I write for the change stream pipeline (`db.collection.watch(changeStreamPipeline)`) if I want any update not include `buyer`.
For example:
The current update description

```js
 updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: {
      'buyer.2.name': "alex",
      'buyer.2.price': 1.4,
      'buyer.2.max': 12146,
      }}
```

I don't want to receive any message of the `updateFields` that start with `buyer`, for exmaple: `buyer.2.name`, `buyer.2.price`.
I tried the following pipeline, but it only works for the update field that exactly is `buyer`:

```js
db.collection.watch(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                operationType: "update",
                "updateDescription.updatedFields.buyer": {
                    $exists: false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add an `$addFields` stage prior to your `$match` stage, in which we'll remove all "buyer" keys from the object before performing the match stage to see if any other fields were updated,

Here is how I did this using `$objectToArray` and `$regexMatch`:

```
const pipeline = [
    {
        $addFields: {
            "updateDescription.updatedFields": {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: {
                            $objectToArray: { $ifNull: ["$updateDescription.updatedFields", {}]}
                        },
                        cond: {
                            $not: { $regexMatch: {input: "$$this.k", regex: /^buyer\..*/,} }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    operationType: {$in: ["update", 'replace']},
                    $expr: {
                        $gt: [
                            {$size: {$objectToArray: { $ifNull: ["$updateDescription.updatedFields", {}]}}},
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    operationType: {$in: ["delete", 'insert']},
                }
            ]
        }
    }
];

const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);
```

Comment: Doing this will also ignore the `insert` and `delete` operation types which is not included `buyer`, can I have them appear? thanks.

Comment: yea, just add just operations to the operationType

Comment: do you mean doing `operationType: {$in: ["update", 'replace', 'delete', 'insert']},`? I tried, but it's not working, when I tried to `remove` or `insert` the whole document, I couldn't receive the message from the change stream.

Comment: that's because `insert` and `delete` operation don't have the "updateDescription" field, i edited my question on how to handle them ( just using an `$or` condidition)